# are there any benefits to running terraform in a docker container

Tags: docker, terraform

I am using terraform to build azure infrastructure and I am curious to know if I gain much by running terraform in a docker container?

I was thinking it would be easy to duplicate environments with parameters.

There are a number of posts about this subject like [this one](https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/treating-your-terraform-like-an-application-why-terraform-in-a-docker-container-31e802314b4).

Comment: As an exercise I was trying to do it, but came across HCP own recommendation: 

*Running Terraform inside a Docker container requires more configuration than running the Terraform CLI executables directly. Unless you need container isolation, we recommend using the non-containerized Terraform CLI packages.*
Source: https://hub.docker.com/r/hashicorp/terraform/
I'l stop trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the question being asked is too broad and general, the answer is relatively straightforward: Yes, you will have everything to gain and nothing to lose.

The concept of **Infrastructure as Code** together with all the rising tools like Terraform has quickly become the de-facto in the DevOps world. Deployment scripts are being treated as an application and hence versioned in code repositories. As a result, this `infrastructure deployment` application has everything a normal application would have:

- OS runtime e.g. redhat, ubuntu, debian, alpine
- System dependencies e.g. terraform, ansible
- Source code
- Application requirements e.g Ansible requirements.txt or Terraform modules
- Configurations e.g environment variables, config files

As with any modern application, you will naturally need to dockerize it for a couple of reasons:

- Encapsulate all the requirements and dependencies into a single image.
- Have different image versions to represent different versions of your deployment code.
- Build once, run everywhere (that support Docker) from your local machine to CI/CD machine.
- Ability to deploy to different environments easily by changing the configurations when running the same docker image.
- Easier to debug and replicate bugs if there are any issues in the CI/CD pipeline.
- Consistent development experience when more than 1 developer is working on the same project.

The list goes on but basically they are the same reasons why you should dockerize your frontend or backend applications.

Comment: great answer, if you are containerising terraform, where do you keep the tfstate?  I use remote storage but where would you store it if containerised?

Comment: When you use remote backend, the tfstate is store in the remote storage like AWS S3 or Azure Storage. You can refer more to this [article](https://blog.gruntwork.io/how-to-manage-terraform-state-28f5697e68fa)

Comment: How do you get credentials into the container to run it?  Do you build a new image every time you change your `.tf` files?  Do you need the root-equivalent permissions to run `docker` commands everywhere you might run Terraform?  What benefit is there over simply keeping your Terraform scripts in source control (and maybe having a CI system run `terraform apply` on commit)?

Comment: Depending on the backend type but you will be able to pass the credential in like AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY as environment variables without hardcoding it, and hence avoid building new images every time.

Comment: You can add a non-root user to docker group and you will be able to run the container that execute Terraform scripts!

Comment: It depends on how complicated your Terraform script is. There will be cases where you have a lot of dependencies and will not want to install all of it into your CI system but rather keep it within your Terraform container. Imagine you have CI server with 10 nodes and every time you add a new dependency, you have to install it to all 10 nodes. You would rather want to just pull the docker image which contains all the necessary runtime environments to execute your task.